# Jquery autocomplete countries flags how to?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need to create an autocomplete `jQuery` script that will filter information from a .csv (or xml etc) file and after select the result will display all the information.
From what I understand I will have to use jquery autocomplete script, that I am studying all the day and I was hoping for a solution.
I have basic+ knownledge of coding and I will need this to filter the results from a text file.
Example of text file .csv is:

```
"UK", "info1", "info2", "info2", "info3"
"ITALY", "info1", "info2", "info2", "info3"
"etc", "info1", "info2", "info2", "info3"
```

So when user type UK the flag will be resulted also and after click on UK the info1,2,3 will display. 
I understand that i need to work on something like this, but how to replace the geo xml with my own xml,csv etc file?
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp
And also how it will be possible to load the flags?

In this example code it will filter from a txt file that has 2 values.
`"12": "Italy",`
How can i add more?
Example : `"12": "125": "54": "Italy",` will not work 
How can i add the flag image also to load?
Here is the complete js:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Load countries then initialize plugin:
    $.ajax({
        url: 'content/countries.txt',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (source) {

        var countriesArray = $.map(source, function (value, key) { return { value: value, data: key }; }),
        countries = $.map(source, function (value) { return value; });

        // Setup jQuery ajax mock:
        $.mockjax({
            url: '*',
            responseTime:  200,
            response: function (settings) {
                var query = settings.data.query,
                queryLowerCase = query.toLowerCase(),
                suggestions = $.grep(countries, function(country) {
                    return country.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) !== -1;
                }),
                response = {
                    query: query,
                    suggestions: suggestions
                };

                this.responseText = JSON.stringify(response);
            }
        });

        // Initialize ajax autocomplete:
        $('#autocomplete-ajax').autocomplete({
            serviceUrl: '/autosuggest/service/url',
            onSelect: function(suggestion) {
                $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
            }
        });

        // Initialize autocomplete with local lookup:
        $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
            lookup: countriesArray,
            onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                $('#selection').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
            }
        });

        // Initialize autocomplete with custom appendTo:
        $('#autocomplete-custom-append').autocomplete({
            lookup: countriesArray,
            appendTo: '#suggestions-container'
        });

    });

});
```

And here is the html:

```
    <h2>Ajax Lookup</h2>
    <p>Type country name in english:</p>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete-ajax"/>
    </div>
    <div id="selction-ajax"></div>

    <h2>Local Lookup</h2>
    <p>Type country name in english:</p>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete"/>
    </div>
    <div id="selection"></div>

    <h2>Custom Lookup Container</h2>
    <p>Type country name in english:</p>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete-custom-append" style="float: left;"/>
        <div id="suggestions-container" style="position: relative; float: left; width: 400px; margin: 10px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/demo.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you post your code so we can help you?

Comment: Edited post with code. I am not sure if this helps, i have opened around 30 tabs and created so many different options that i do not know what to follow. Basically i need to do this: http://www.localphone.com/prices

Comment: Hi Sorry for not beeing clear. I edited again post , this is the correct code i need to use, please read. Thank you.

Comment: somebody give me a qlue here? i did paste the jquery, i do not know what else to do. This script should be ok, what i need is to also add country flag and make it filter from a .txt file more options. Currently there are only 2. Example: `"Country" : "option"` . I really need it to be like : `"img flag", "Country", "option", "option2", "option3+url href"` I am just CSS,Html guy, please some help.